discarding lookahead token INTEGER
I want to use lex&yacc to parse student number and name, from a csv file, using  . But the parser is failing to read after the INTEGER.
If I print FOUND <  it will not print after the INTEGER. What is missing?
I am using bison
Starting parse
Entering state 0
Stack now 0
Reading a token
<12345> 
Found '<'
INTEGER: 12345
Next token is token INTEGER ()
Error: syntax error
Cleanup: discarding lookahead token INTEGER ()
Stack now 0
my lex file is:
%{
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "alunos.tab.h"
/* Declaração da função yyerror */
void yyerror(char *s);
%}

%%
"<"            ;  /* Ignorar o caractere '<' */
">"            ;  /* Ignorar o caractere '>' */
[0-9]{5}       { printf("INTEGER: %s\n", yytext); yylval.ival = atoi(yytext); return INTEGER; }
[a-zA-Z]+      { printf("NAME: %s\n", yytext); yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return NAME; }
[ \t\n]+       ;  /* Ignorar espaços em branco e novas linhas */
.              { printf("INVALID: %s\n", yytext); yyerror("invalid character"); }
%%

int yywrap(void){
    return 1;
}

and my yacc file is:
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int yylex(void);
void yyerror(char *);
#define YYDEBUG 1  // Enable debugging
%}

%union {
    int ival;
    char *sval;
}

%token <ival> INTEGER
%token <sval> NAME

%%
sequence:
    '<' INTEGER '>' '<' NAME '>' { printf("Sequência: Numero: %d, Nome: %s\n", $2, $5); free($5); }
    ;
%%

int main(void) {
    yydebug = 1;  // Enable debugging output
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}

void yyerror(char *s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", s);
}


What is the minimal example that results in this error?
